# Vim, location of vimfiles, on windows

Tags: vim

I am still new to vim. On Windows, it seems that I have 2 locations: `$home/vimfiles` and `$vim/vimfiles` (by `help runtimepath`).

I see both paths in the explorer. Which one is the one to use, where shall I install new bundles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configuration should happen in `$home\vimfiles\`.

Comment: thank you! I also found this note http://agateau.com/2007/note-to-self-path-to-vim-files-on-windows/ suggesting that in non-win systems it might be different, well, that's why the tutorials might show different behavior.